# Ubuntu 13.04 background is white when handled by file manager, and has no background when it is not

Tags: gnome, nautilus, ppa, 13.04, desktop-background

Long story short, I installed Ubuntu 13.04, and added the Gnome PPA but after installation I realized that the background was now white/grey. I tried ppa purging the gnome ppa but it failed. Upon right clicking the desktop i realized it was the standard nautilus right click menu so I disabled the file manager from handling the desktop and now my background is nothing. It takes whatever was open last before it was closed and displays that and it disables my minimize function so currently the file manager is handling my desktop so It can function properly. Basically my question is how do I set my computer back to its original configuration without reinstalling Ubuntu again, or more simply, how can I get my background back. Thanks a lot.